# Printer installation problems under ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, printing

I moved from 12.04 to 14.04 and I am no more able to print.

This is a network printer and if I try to print something the printer completely freezes (one need to restart it by unplugging the supply !).

The printer is a Konica Minolta BizHub C280.

I have tryed 3 different Ubuntu installations:
- Ubuntu 14.04 (64bits)
- Xubuntu 14.04 (64bits)
- Ubuntu 14.04 (32bits) [as my 12.04 was a 32bits)

I think the short term solution is to come back to 12.04 !

Comment: Did you try manually selecting different printer drivers? If your printer has multiple drivers, perhaps one of them is faulty.

Answer (score 1):

When I moved to 14.04 I got problems with my Brother HL-5350DN.
Now I have installed it thru:
localhost for CUPS (C Unix Printing System)

```
    http://localhost:631/
```

and it works just fine.

So try that instead by the Printers dialog.

/Göran